# Migrate statistics

Tags: migrations, nodes

Is there an automatic way to import, with migrate, statistics (from core module statistics) from d7 to d8?

The "dirty" way could be export statistics from d7, loop on these values and then run a insert query on node_counter table..

Answer (score -1):

Support for this is being added to Drupal 8 core: https://www.drupal.org/node/2500521. You can try applying the latest patch and seeing if it works for you (and if so - or, if not - please report back in the issue!).

Thanks.